# Binary Serialization, I think I almost have it working

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been following a guide on Binary Serialization (this one here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C) and I think I finally almost have it working. When I save the file is created, but when I try to load, nothing is loaded. I feel like I'm close to getting this working. Any advice would be appreciated. Here's the code:

Save/Load class

```
[Serializable()]
public class SaveLoad : ISerializable
{
    public int GameDay = Date.GameDay;
    public List<Adventurer> Adventurers = FormMain.AdventurerManager.AdventurerList;

    public SaveLoad()
    {
        GameDay = 0;
        Adventurers = null;
    }

    public SaveLoad(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        GameDay = (int)info.GetValue("Date", typeof(int));
        Adventurers = (List<Adventurer>)info.GetValue("Adventurers", typeof(List<Adventurer>));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        info.AddValue("Date", GameDay);
        info.AddValue("Adventurers", Adventurers);
    }
}
```

Save/Load methods:

```
    void btnSaveGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveLoad save = new SaveLoad();

        Stream stream = File.Open("SaveGame.osl", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        bformatter.Serialize(stream, save);
        stream.Close();
    }

    void btnLoadGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveLoad load = new SaveLoad();

        Stream stream = File.Open("SaveGame.osl", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        load = (SaveLoad)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();

        Date.CalculateDate();

        this.Visible = false;
        ((FormMain)(this.ParentForm)).ControlMainScreen.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: Do you get `null`? Or do you get an instance both `GameDay` and `Adventurers` are `null`? I noticed, when you are loading, you create a new instance of `SaveLoad` but a few lines done you create another one by deserializing. Perhapse you looked in the wrong instance?

Comment: I figured that was the case. in the tutorial GetObjectData is never called and I'm guessing that's what's wrong. What needs to happen for it to work?

Comment: @MartinMulder When I click on the load game button, the screen goes back to the main screen, but that's all that happens. Either Load does nothing or save doesn't save properly.

Comment: What happens if you add a breakpoint at line `Stream.Close()`. What kind of date is inside `sl`?

Comment: The breakpoint does nothing. The program stops there but that's it. I also changed Date to GameDay, which is an int. I'm going to modify the code in my OP.

Comment: The breakpoint does nothing? Of course it does something: it breaks the execution of your program. You still did not tell what you see inside `sl` at that breakpoint.

Comment: For the btnSaveGame_Click event

ReadTimeout = 'stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

WriteTimeout = 'stream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: What makes you feel you have to implement `ISerializable` explicitly? - do you have any weird data types in `Adventurers` that are not automatically serializable? If not, your SaveLoad class _should_ automagically serialize and deserialize properly to and from binary just with the [Serializable()] decoration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may just have an initialization timing issue.

Try either moving you initialization of the GameDay and Adventurers to the constructor or get rid of the nulling them out in the constructor.  Once I did the following, the code pretty much works:

```
public SaveLoad()
{
    //GameDay = null;
    //Adventurers = null;
}
```

Note I had to also make sure that the Adventurer class had the Serialization attribute.

Here is the code with the serialization that works for me (I had to create my own Adventurer class and I replaced the date with a string since I couldn't figure out what you were doing with it or where it was coming from.  I also populated the adventurers list with some dummy data and commented out anything to do with the form stuff that I also didn't have information on.

```
[Serializable()]
public class SaveLoad : ISerializable
{
    public string GameDay = null;
    public List<Adventurer> Adventurers = null; 
        //FormMain.AdventurerManager.AdventurerList;

    public SaveLoad()
    {
        GameDay = "Date";
        Adventurers = new List<Adventurer>() { new Adventurer { Name = "a1", Type = "t1" }, new Adventurer { Name = "a1", Type = "t1" } }; ;
    }

    public SaveLoad(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        GameDay = (string)info.GetValue("Date", typeof(string));
        Adventurers = (List<Adventurer>)info.GetValue("Adventurers", typeof(List<Adventurer>));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        info.AddValue("Date", GameDay);
        info.AddValue("Adventurers", Adventurers);
    }
}
[Serializable()]
public class Adventurer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

private void btnLoadGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveLoad sl = new SaveLoad();

        Stream stream = File.Open("SaveGame.osl", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        sl = (SaveLoad)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(sl.Adventurers.Count.ToString());
        //Date.CalculateDate();

        //this.Visible = false;
        //((Form1)(this.ParentForm)).ControlMainScreen.Visible = true;

    }

    private void btnSaveGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveLoad sl = new SaveLoad();

        Stream stream = File.Open("SaveGame.osl", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        bformatter.Serialize(stream, sl);
        stream.Close();

    }
```

Comment: When you initialize the fields outside of the constructor like that, they get compiled into the first few lines of your constructors - which means they will get added just before you set them to null and 0.  So you'll need to remove those 2 lines from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

@JasonHaley is right, you have a timing/initialization issue.

During your Load button click event your defining a new SaveLoad called "Load"

This creates a reference to the FormMain.AdventurerManager.AdventurerList

But during deserialization this reference is destroyed by the object that was serialized to disk (the other list of adventurers) and is now a DIFFERENT list of adventurers from the one defined in your FormMain.AdventurerManager.AdventurerList

You need to load into that list specifically...

```
void btnLoadGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream stream = File.Open("SaveGame.osl", FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    SaveLoad load = (SaveLoad)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
    // ***********************************
    FormMain.AdventurerManager.AdventurerList = SaveLoad.Adventurers
    // ***********************************

    stream.Close();

    Date.CalculateDate();

    this.Visible = false;
    ((FormMain)(this.ParentForm)).ControlMainScreen.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I am not an experienced programmer but I really am trying here.